# How to put a web element into my android application?

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, ip-camera

im making an app with the aim of monitoring my university's parking lot's lines using mobile devices (android in this case), so i'm gonna use ip cameras that live stream the video into a webpage, so i would like to take that element (live streaming) and display it on the application.

Does anyone know how to this? i have read about webView, but im not 100% sure if it lets me display only an element of the webpage and not the whole thing.

Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: In  WebView, you load the html file, so you can dispaly all elements of your webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView and enable all the features to make sure that all elements can display correctly. Im not sure at all what you want to show, but the documentation of WebView can be helpful for you

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html